# What options make MathJax accessible by blind and visually impaired people?

Tags: mathjax

Is there any support to read MathJax using screen readers?

If yes, how do I enable it? What options should I use?

Some example would be great, because I read about accessibility options, but had no access in applying them.

Comment: The short answer is yes but you might want to share what you've tried (e.g., using the code snippet editor). The documentation at http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/basic/accessibility.html#mathjax-accessibility-extensions and http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/accessibility.html#explorer-extension-options would be the starting point in any case.

Comment: I just copied the configuration block from http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/accessibility.html#explorer-extension-options But doesn't see no change to formulas, except collapsing. How does this work?

Comment: Well, you won't see a change. But screenreader users will get appropriate information for voicing from additional markup. The explorer feature can be used and if you use the mathjax menu to switch on the subtitle feature, you'll see them visibly. MathJax's YouTube channel has a few demo videos.